# UIButton Image doesn't changes in a "for" loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

i have a question:
I designed my GUI without the InterfaceBuilder,
now i want change the image of a button for a short period of time,
but it won't change, until the whole for-loop has finished.
What am i doing wrong?

```
    for (size_t i=0; i< 100; ++i){
      switch (variable) {
        case 0:
          [self changeRedButtonToWhite: redButton];
        break;
        case 1:
        ....
      }
    }

-(IBAction) changeRedButtonToWhite: (id)sender{
    [sender setBackgroundImage: whiteImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: What is the starting value of variable?  Also, what is the reason for the for loop and switch/case statment?

Comment: variable is unimportant. when variable is 0 nothing happens. thats the point ?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a for loop to do this, you should try using an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) instead. The UI isn't refreshed while there is a loop going on inside the main thread.

Comment: But how can i do that? I have four colors and i want them to flash randomly, thats Variable. So the only way i thought i can do that is with a for - loop

Comment: Have a `NSTimer` with a very short timelapse call a method that changes your color's button randomly.

Answer (score 1):

@Luzal's explanation is correct. You're setting the background color of the button, but that only causes the button to be marked as needing to be redrawn. The redrawing doesn't happen (at least) until execution returns to the run loop, and that can't happen until your for loop finishes.

We can't tell from the code you posted what else you're doing in you for loop, but if you're using it as the delay mechanism and then changing the button color back to red when, say, `variable` hits 99, that's not a great plan anyway. You can use NSTimer to manage the duration of the color change, or -performSelector:afterDelay:, or use Core Animation.

Answer (score 0):

Put the for-loop on a background thread and call the -changeRedButtonToWhite on the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not do the following?

Add all your buttons to an `NSMutableArray`, or just use `NSArray` if your not planning on adding more buttons to it after it has been allocated.

```
NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, button2, button3, nil]; //and so on....
```

and then....

```
for(UIButton *button in buttonsArray){
     [button setBackgroundImage: whiteImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```